# 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xeb' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128) with urlopen(req).read()

Tags: python, character-encoding, django-views

I am trying to retrieve automatically the image link of a news article and I wrote a python module ***imageprocessor*** with the ***getimage*** function, which identifies for a news article the image link:

```
req = Request('http://top-channel.tv/artikull.php?id=264806&ref=fp', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
c = urlopen(req).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(c)
m = soup.find('link',{'rel' : 'image_src'})
return m['href']
```

When I run from shell, it works fine:

```
import imageprocessor
img=imageprocessor.getimage('http://top-channel.tv/artikull.php?id=264806&ref=fp','Top Channel')
img
'http://www.top-channel.tv/foto/lajme/ELBASA-NDERTIMET-07_17.jpg'
```

The problem is when i try to call this function the same way from views.py module (Django framework), the browser shows this error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /fillimi/

'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xeb' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I seems like c = urlopen(req).read() returns assci encoded string. I tried:

```
img=img.encode('utf-8')
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to decode your string first.
Try this:

```
img = urllib.urlopen(link).read()
img = img.decode(<source encoding>)
img = unicode_str.encode("utf8")
```

An example could be:

```
img= '\xa0'
img = img.decode("windows-1252")
img = img.encode("utf8")
```

Comment: I tried to decode/encode but it gives me: 'AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode''

Comment: When I try 'c = urlopen(req).read() c=c.decode(<source encoding>)', it gives: ''charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6320: character maps to <undefined>'